# How to run automated Tests in Azure Test Plans

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I want to be able to run automated tests from within Azure Test Plans and define everything in a yml file.

What I've done:
I have a repository in azure DevOps containing several tests written in .NET core. Those are associated to a testcase in azure test plans. 
I also have created a azure pipeline by adding a .yml file to my repo. This pipeline consists of two stages, one for the build and one which actually runs all tests on a nightly schedule.

However, I want the manual testers to be able to trigger the automated tests from within Azure Test Plans too. The official docs say one must create a release pipeline to do so. So my questions are:

1. Why do I need a release pipeline? I already have my build pipeline, I won't do any release, I just want to be able to run my tests from within test plans by button click.
2. If I really have to create release pipeline, how can i define this in a yml file? The official docs only mention the "Classic", manual steps within azure DevOps, but I don't want to add pipelines manually, I want to have everything defined in yml files.
3. Is there a possibility to run my tests containerized? I do it already in my build pipeline, but since I couldn't find a way to define release pipelines in yml, I don't know how to run them in docker containers.

Comment: Is my answer helpful for your questions? Or do you still have other questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Azure Pipelines offers a compelling orchestration workflow to obtain test binaries as artifacts and run tests. This workflow shares the same concepts used in the scheduled testing workflow, meaning users running tests in scheduled workflow will find it easy adapt; for example, by cloning an existing scheduled testing release pipeline.
   Another major benefit is the availability of a rich set of tasks catalog that enable a range of activates to be performed before and after running tests. Examples include preparing and cleaning test data, creating and cleaning configuration files, and more.
2. To define release pipeline in yml, you should go to the preview features page and turn on the toggle for “Multi-stage pipelines”. 
   Below is a simple sample.

> ```
> stages:
> - stage: Build
>   jobs:
>   - job: Build
>     pool:
>       vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
>     continueOnError: true
>     steps:
>     - script: echo my first build job
> - stage: Deploy
>   jobs:
>     # track deployments on the environment
>   - deployment: DeployWeb
>     pool:
>       vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
>     # creates an environment if it doesn’t exist
>     environment: 'smarthotel-dev'
>     strategy:
>       # default deployment strategy
>       runOnce:
>         deploy:
>           steps:
>           - script: echo my first deployment
> ```

More detailed information, you can refer to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/

Comment: I am aware of multistage pipelines, but there are two kind of pipelines: Build Pipelines and Release Pipelines. While there is the possibility to define multiple stages for both of it, I only find a way using yaml files for build pipelines, not for release pipelines. So your answer doesn't fit my question unfortunately.

Comment: Actually,  the Multistage pipelines is a new feature and provides functionality for deployment using "Environments". Most of the features are same as release pipeline.  In different stages, you can use different agent and different tasks. If you still want a separate release yaml feature, here is a suggest ticket about it https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365687/pipeline-as-code.html, and the status is On Roadmap, it means Microsoft has accepted this feature request and will update it in subsequent version.